# Getting Alert Query Conditions in Grafana Alert messages

Tags: grafana, monitoring, grafana-alerts

I'm trying to set up alerting using grafana(v9.3).
I want the details of the evaluating conditions which were used for generating the alert (as logic can be different for different alerts, but goto the same channel).

[image: Setting alert conditions]

I can get the metric in question and the evaluated value from `$values` variable, but I want to get the expression/functions in use for evaluating the alert.

This is the info I can get using annotations:

```
...
"commonAnnotations": {
        "__dashboardUid__": "wjKb-HaVz",
        "__orgId__": "1",
        "__panelId__": "2",
        "__value_string__": "[ var='B' labels={name=caragor.request_count.domain-com} value=495 ], [ var='C' labels={name=caragor.request_count.domain-com} value=1 ]",
        "__values__": "{\"B\":495,\"C\":1}",
        "labels": "map[__alert_rule_namespace_uid__:KckuaNa4z __alert_rule_uid__:KNe9-Na4k alertname:Sample Alert grafana_folder:req name:caragor.request_count.domain-com]",
        "values": "map[B:495 C:1]"
    },
    ...
```

I've gone through [this](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/fundamentals/annotation-label/variables-label-annotation/) documentation link and it explains about labels and values, but I can't find a way to get the condition information.

The information I want is something like `<query> <expression_type> <function> <input> <threshold>`
eg. here for the above image would be

```
B reduce last A null
C threshold is_below B 5000
```

Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: Let me reiterate: you know how to substitute the values of steps, but want also to provide details of how these values were achieved?

Comment: yes, something like the alert was triggered because the current calulated value (say **4500**), breached a **threshold** and it **is_below 5000**. Something like that.

Right now I can get that the calculated value was (lets say *4500*) and hence the alert was triggered.

Comment: Well... I think most of what you want could be achieved through alert templates for different "alert families" (like 2-step-treshold-below, 3-step-treshold-above and so on), but I don't think you could get threshold value itself at the moment of alert generation.

Comment: yes, that can be done, I just wanted to know if I could get the data in the alert template itself, given that the functions are already saved in order to evaluate the actual alerting metric.